# Jetpack Compose TextField not updating when typing a new character

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, mutablestateof

I followed [this document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) from the developer site.
I want to display the text in an `OutlinedTextField` from a user input, and have it survive configuration changes.

With the code below, when the user inputs the text from the keyboard, `OutlinedTextField` doesn't update the text.

```
HelloContent(name = city.name, onNameChange = { city.name = it})//Doesn't work
```

[image]

However this line of code works properly:

```
HelloContent(name = temp, onNameChange = { temp = it})//Work
```

Below is the code which I use to implement:

```
@Composable
fun HelloScreen() {
    var city by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = CitySaver) {
        mutableStateOf(City("Hanoi","VietNam"))
    }
    var temp by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column {
        HelloContent(name = city.name, onNameChange = { city.name = it})//Doesn't work
        HelloContent(name = temp, onNameChange = { temp = it})//Work
    }
}
@Composable
    fun HelloContent(name: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello, $name",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
            )
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = name,
                onValueChange = onNameChange,
                label = { Text("Name") }
            )
        }
    }
data class City(var name: String, val country: String)
val CitySaver = run {
    val nameKey = "Name"
    val countryKey = "Country"
    mapSaver(save = {mapOf(nameKey to it.name,countryKey to it.country)},
        restore = {City(it[nameKey] as String,it[countryKey] as String)})
}
```

Could you help me to fix the first  code block to work?

```
HelloContent(name = city.name, onNameChange = { city.name = it})//Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TextField` will not be updated because you are only modifying `city.name` not the actual **mutableState** `City` object so there is nothing that tells the `composer` to trigger an update (`re-composition`).

So modify your first `HelloContent` composable like this.

```
 HelloContent(name = city.name, onNameChange = { city = city.copy(name = it)})
```

changing this line

```
onNameChange = { city.name = it}
```

to this

```
onNameChange = { city = city.copy(name = it)}
```

will make sure your `TextField` gets updated(`re-composed`).

Keep in mind, invoking `.copy()` on data classes guarantees a new instance will be created (provided that you supplied a new value to one of its properties/fields), which is needed by `Compose` to trigger `re-composition`.